# How to deploy src/main/webapp folder (Maven) as an application in JBoss7?

Tags: java, maven, java-ee-6, war, jboss7.x

I want to deploy my src/main/webapp folder from Maven project as an application in JBoss7. What I'm trying to do is to:

- save and refresh xhtml, css, js etc.
- do `mvn prepare-package war:inplace` for full deployment

This is of course for development only. I want to have similar workflow as with Maven Jetty plugin but for JEE6 app.

Deployment scanner is looking for *.war directories.

My current solutions:

- use jboss-as-maven-plugin to deploy on package phase - with this I need to redeploy on each CSS, JS or XHTML change
- add my target folder to deployment-scanner and do `war:exploded` to copy resources to war dir. Full redeployment needs creating .dodeploy file with antrun plugin and this is quite ugly. I still need to run maven after saving resources. I don't want my resources to be copied anywhere.

There is nothing special in my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.pg</groupId>
<artifactId>jeesample</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>jeesample</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>jeesample.war</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>


</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: can you show us your pom? do you want to deploy only via maven (cmd) or via your IDE as well?

Comment: Pom added. For now it makes me no difference if I deploy from cmd or IDE. I tried with JBoss plugin for eclipse. It was copying resources well but the war file build with this plugin was lacking jars and some classes. It was not using maven for war assembly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use the [maven-war-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/). Maven should add your depenendencies. Note, however, that JBoss 7 has a new module dependency system, so if you want to use some internal modules provided by jboss you have to state them in your MANIFEST.MF file as in the example and mark them as provided in the pom.xml. JBoss 7 reads the manifest and loads the modules upon deploy

Here is an example that works for me:

```
    ...
    <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Built-By>Dev Team</Built-By>
                        <Dependencies>javaee.api, javax.faces.api, javax.xml.rpc.api,
                            org.joda.time, org.hibernate, org.hibernate.validator,
                            org.dom4j, org.picketlink</Dependencies>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
     ...
```

With this config the correct war is created (mvn war:war). Also when I right click on the project in eclipse and choose > 'Run on Server' the war is deployed correctly. Resources such as xhtml, etc are automatically redeployed on save and the changes are visible upon refresh.
I also have the m2eclipse plugin installed

Comment: This is strange. Everyting works fine when I deploy application my way. However when I deploy via Eclipse's "Run on Server" I get for example : `/viewScopeSample.xhtml: The class 'com.pg.jeesample.ui.SimpleViewBean' does not have the property 'addToCounter'` The bean of course contains such method.

Comment: make a project clean and redeploy. Also check if everything is correctly copied into the deployment folder of JBoss

Comment: It is not copied correctly. WEB-INF/lib is empty while it contains primefaces and slf4j in my target dir. Do you have JBoss tools installed on Eclipse? I don't. I've just downloaded JBoss 7 server descriptir. Maybe I need maven integration for jee projects or something. It seems for me that eclipse is using its internal build system to assembly war and ignores maven.

Comment: Go to the project properties (ctrl+I/cmd+I) > Deployment Assembly and check if the Maven Dependencies are added. If not add them as Source and choose WEB-INF/lib as the deploy path

Comment: Some tricks with Deployment Assembly did the trick. Thanks. This is a good workaround however this don't answer my question. I'm going to accept the answer as it seems that my idea is impossible to implement.

Answer (score 0):

if you can switch to play framework, this will increase productivity very much. reall... it's like ruby on rails.

Also if you are using maven, probably this can help to automatically deploy EAR during install phase

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>ear</type>
                <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                <outputDirectory>${jboss-inst}/deploy</outputDirectory>
            </artifactItem>
        </artifactItems>
        <skip>${skip.ear.auto.deployment}</skip>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I know play framework. Thanks. What you're suggesting forces me to redeploy webapp to see changes on single xhtml. For this j can use jboss plugin easier. What I want to achieve is to save XHTML file and refresh browser to see changes.